# How to reshape my data for the convolution neural network model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I need to let input in my convolution neural network model a reshaping data, 
But  my problem is with line of code:

```
model = Sequential()
input_traces = Input(shape=(3253,))
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, 
activation='relu',input_shape = input_traces))
```

This line gives me this error:

```
   CNN_Based_Attack.py:139: UserWarning: Update your `Conv1D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv1D(activation="relu", input_shape=(None, /in..., padding="same", filters=32, kernel_size=3)`
  model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, border_mode='same', activation='relu',input_dim=input_traces))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN_Based_Attack.py", line 139, in <module>
    model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, border_mode='same', activation='relu',input_dim=input_traces))
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 430, in add layer(x)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 557, in __call_self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 134, in build
    constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 390, in add_weight
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/initializers.py", line 200, in __call__
    scale /= max(1., float(fan_in + fan_out) / 2)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

When I try to mdify it:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, 
activation='relu',input_shape = (500000, 3253)))
```

It gives this error:

```
/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py:834: UserWarning: The `nb_epoch` argument in `fit` has been renamed `epochs`.
  warnings.warn('The `nb_epoch` argument in `fit` '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN_Based_Attack.py", line 113, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=15, nb_epoch=30)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 853, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1424, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1300, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 127, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (500000, 3253)
```

I really don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the old version of Keras (since the [release 2.0](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/releases/tag/2.0.0), `nb_filter` has changed to `filters`, therefore, you should follow the old documentation (e.g. [this one](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/convolutional/)) instead.

In the first snippet, I suppose the problem is in this part: `input_shape = input_traces`. The `Convolution1D` constructor expects a `tuple`, e.g. `(32, 100, 3)`, but `input_traces` is initialized as a Keras layer.

In the second snipped, you passed a `tuple` instead, which is correct. The errors says that it expects the `input_shape` to have 3 dimensions instead of 2. First, I want to point out that `nb_filter` means *'number of filters per batch of data'*. So, the `input_shape` must also include the `bach_size` (in case if you are not familiar with this concept, there is a [wonderful answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) that covers everything you need to know about batches). So, just pass

```
Convolution1D(..., input_shape = (batch_size, data_length, numof_channels), ...)
```

and everything should work (in case if you are wondering what is `numof_channels`, it is similar to how an image have 3 channels: red, green, and blue). If you want to have an arbitrary `bach_size`, you can pass `input_shape = (None, data_length, numof_channels)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, in my case I don't analyse images but a float  data ( some chip consumption acquisition) so for that I don't have any channel, must I put them numod_channel= None

Comment: @tierrytestu if you just have float values, then in your case `numof_channels = 1`. I am not really familiar with Keras 1, but I hope my answer works.